# Twitter Bootstrap 3 - not collapse nav nav-tabs

Tags: twitter-bootstrap-3

how to disable collapse in **nav nav-tabs nav-justified** - http://www.bootply.com/123035

When is open on mobile nav-tabs is collapse.

I need **nav-justified**. I need nav-tabs center.

Thanks

Comment: You mean it's collapsed by default?

Comment: Your question isn't very clear. The reason it collapses on mobile is to make it fit on the screen. To disable that, you can [either follow the instructions to make BS3 non-responsive](http://getbootstrap.com/getting-started/#disable-responsive) or write your own styles to make it work on small screens.

Answer (score 2):

You could add this CSS to override Bootstrap's stacking/collapse behavior..

```
.nav-justified>li {
    display: table-cell;
    float:left;
}
```

http://www.bootply.com/123059